# How to plus or minus one from the end of a string variable

Tags: javascript, string

What I am trying to do is take variable thats a string followed by a number, and convert it to a new variable that is the same string but a different number.

I currently have

```
var image = 'image1';
```

When user clicks next, I need to make a variable that takes the image var, and return `'image2'`.

```
function nextImage() {
    nextimage = image + 1;
}
```

Comment: That's not even valid javascript (and has nothing to do with jQuery at all).
You should read some basic, beginner grade javascript tutorials.

Comment: It is not a typographical error, really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method which can accepts a regular expression and replacement callback function:

```
var image = 'image1';
var nextimage = image.replace(/\d+$/, function(match) {
    return +match + 1;
});
nextimage; // "image2"
```

The section "[specifying a function as a parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)" explains how the callback function works in detail.

Comment: @amit it can, however, help others. That's why it's a Q&A site

Comment: @Tivie, Salman, removed my comment, you might be right. I just feel this type of question shouldn't even stay here (and looks like it going away soon anyway)

Comment: @DavidProvost - If I may offer a suggestion... Be sure to take the time to fully understand how this code snippet works. Don't just copy and paste it, make sure you understand every detail. If there's anything you don't understand, read up on it; don't put that on the back burner. A great place to start would be the [MDN documentation for the .replace method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) - it explains it thoroughly and has a bunch of nifty examples. Happy hacking!

Comment: @Michael Geary - Thank you for your comment. I have experience working with regular expressions in sed, but never before javascript.  Thank you for that link as its exactly what I need to read up on to understand how this works.  When I need it again I will come back to this post.

Answer (score 1):

This should work out for you.

```
var image = "image1";

function nextImage(){    
    var index = image.slice(-1);

    index++;

    return nextimage = 'image' + index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is without using Regular Expressions. You can extract the image name and the image number from the variable itself and add 1 on each click.

```
function nextImage() {
   image=image.slice(0, "image".length) + (Number(image.slice("image".length, image.length)) + 1);
   return image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is javascript method that increment the number of images

```
// initially number of images = 1 , you can change it
var image = "image1";
function nextImage(e)
{
    var curr = image.substr(5);
    curr = parseInt(curr) + 1;
    image = "image" + curr;
    alert(image);
    e.preventDefault();
}

window.onload = function(){
    // this is the button that will increment images number by clicking on it
    var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
    btn.addEventListener("click",nextImage);
};
```

but this in you html code

```
<button id="btn">click</button>
```